# Where is @jupyterlab/vega6-extension?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, altair

I'm trying to use an alternative renderer for [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html). The instructions says to install `@jupyterlab/vega6-extension` for offline rendering. However, when I type in

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/vega6-extension
```

I get the following message.

```
ValueError: "@jupyterlab/vega6-extension" is not a valid npm package
```

A [NPM search](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40jupyterlab%2Fvega6-extension) returns nothing as well.

On the site, it says that Jupyter 2.0 will come with this extension installed by default. I am willing to install Jupyter 2.0, except that I don't think it's been released on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab/) (v1.2.4) or [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyterlab) (v1.2.4).

The jupyter packages I see with `conda --list` are as follows.

```
altair                    4.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py37_1  
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                1.2.3              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0
vega                      2.6.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
vega_datasets             0.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
```

Any ideas on how to get this extension for Jupyter Lab?

[Issue 673](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/673) got me down this rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jupyterlab extension that supports Altair 4.0 is not available yet. Altair and JupyterLab tend to have vastly different release cadences, which has historically been particularly challenging for JupyterLab users around major releases of Altair. This is one reason that Altair has been moving toward a model where charts can be rendered independently of such frontend extensions.

Altair 4.0 will display charts in JupyterLab using its default renderer, without the need for installing or enabling any frontend extensions.

As for Issue #673: the information there is long out of date. If you want to hide the actions menu in Altair 4.0, you can use `alt.renderers.set_embed_options(actions=False)`; this does not require switching from the default renderer. For example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.renderers.set_embed_options(actions=False)

alt.Chart(data.cars()).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
).interactive()
```

[image]

Comment: What's the right versions of `altair`, `vega_datasets` and `vega` to use `@jupyterlab/vega5-extension`?

Comment: The current vega5 extension supports altair version 3.X. vega_datasets does not depend on any of this, and the [vega](https://github.com/vega/ipyvega) package is not relevant because it has to do with the jupyer notebook, not jupyterlab.

Comment: If that all seems overly confusing, that's exactly why we're moving toward a world where frontend extensions are optional.